# Not get autofit based on maximum length cell width to all other columns in xaml grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am Using treeview in XAML. Inside the treeview item am having 3 grid columns. First Column in logo which is common width. but second and third column width is based on text which is binding from backend. The second column not resizing based on max width cell that particular column based on rows values.

Please refer below screenshot
[image]

I want this file location text (Gray text) start at same position based on previous column max cell width.
Below is my code

```
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate
                <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="a"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="b"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="c"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="12" Margin="0,0,4,0" Height="auto" Source="img.png""/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding kmkmkmkm}" Margin="0,7,0,0"  Height="20" FontSize="12">   
                    </TextBlock>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding loc}" Margin="10,7,0,0" Height="20" FontSize="12" Foreground="Gray">

                    </TextBlock>


                </Grid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Suggest  me on this.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing many solution, found we cannot share like this with shared size scope.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <Grid Name="Grid2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Width="250">
</StackPanel>
 <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2">
</TextBlock>
</Grid>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```